# Evaluating XPath an XmlResourceParser causes Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I have and XML-file in my resources which looks like this (removed other stage-elemets):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schedule name="Irgend ein besondere Zuchtname">
    <stages>
        <stage interval="0" token="3">
            <name>Name</name>
            <descrition>Some description...</descrition>
            <image>image_to_retrieve.jpg</image>
        </stage>
    </stages>
</schedule>
```

I want to get the text of the image-element for a specific stage (by a token). My approach is this:

```java
public String GetImage(int stageToken) {

    // because this is a helper class, the context is set in the constructor
    XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.schedule_default);
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String image;

    try {
        // error occurs here:
        image = xPath.evaluate("//stage[@token=3]/image/text()", parser);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error evaluating xpath expression.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    parser.close();
    return image;
}
```

The expression shouldn't be the problem, because I tested it with other XPath-programms. Same for the validity of the XML.
This is the exception I get:

```
01-17 00:12:05.044 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMAxisTraverser org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM.getAxisTraverser(int)' on a null object reference
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:295)
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:371)
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at at.beekeeper.util.ScheduleParser.GetImage(ScheduleParser.java:108)
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at at.beekeeper.view.StageActivity.onCreate(StageActivity.java:52)
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
01-17 00:12:05.045 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err: Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMAxisTraverser org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM.getAxisTraverser(int)' on a null object reference
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:365)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:219)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:   ... 16 more
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMAxisTraverser org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM.getAxisTraverser(int)' on a null object reference
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.axes.AxesWalker.setRoot(AxesWalker.java:221)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.setRoot(WalkingIterator.java:157)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:265)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:212)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:     at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:337)
01-17 00:12:05.046 30417-30417/at.beekeeper W/System.err:   ... 18 more
```

Comment: No idea of Android programming, but try using `//stage[@token='3']/image/text()`. Wild guess, but "int" is mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: No as mentioned in my question, the expression isn't the problem, as i have also tried other simper expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to use XPath. You need to use an InputSource and put the XML-file into the /raw directory.

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.schedule_default));
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String image;       

try {
    image = xPath.evaluate("//stage[@token=3]/image/text()", inputSource);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error evaluating xpath expression.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

But I'm still not sure if it is possible to use the XmlPullParser with XPath...